# Is it possible to keep my code style preferences permanent in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

To set your own code style preferences in Android Studio, the following steps would be followed:

```
File > Settings (Ctrl + Alt + S) > Editor > Code Style > Java.
```

or

```
File > Settings (Ctrl + Alt + S) > Editor > Code Style > Kotlin.
```

The scheme choices would be the following:

[image: Andriod Studio Editor Code Style Scheme]

However, when I do restart android studio these changes are not saved.

There have been times when I have had to Invalidate the Caches and Restart Android Studio. Would this have result in these preferences being lost? As my understanding of the clearing, the cache is code changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you navigate to `app > .idea > codeStyles` folder you can see the `codeStyleConfig` and the `Project` code style, the `codeStyleConfig` lets the ide know which code style you have set whilst the `Project` file is an xml representation of the code style you defined in the settings.

I'm not sure why they are being cleared when restarting but you can add exceptions to these files in your gitignore file so that they can be committed, that way they should remain consistent even if you check the project out on another computer.

```
# IDEA/Android Studio ignore exceptions
!/.idea/codeStyles
```